# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Chrome driver to collect data from the web. I have developed a Java application that uses selenium to achieve that. It works fine but after a while (It changes, an hour, a day, a few days, a few weeks, etc.) It gives that exception shown below and stops parsing data. In my application I never call driver.quit() or driver.close(), it is always active and listens to a queue, and if there is any new data start processing.

Why am I getting this exception, what am I doing wrong? Also, I am sharing the Chrome driver startup configuration below.

Thanks.

launch code snippet

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPathChrome);
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY, "/dev/null");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
options.addArguments(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");

options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");


if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(driverChromeOptions)) {
    String optionsArray[] = driverChromeOptions.split("&");
    options.addArguments(optionsArray);
}

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

chrome driver configuration params:

*driver.chrome.options=--disable-extensions&--disable-gpu&--no-first-run&--no-default-browser-check&--ignore-certificate-errors&--window-size=1920,1080&--disable-dev-shm-usage&--disable-infobars*

exception taken after a while (sometimes after an hour, sometimes after a day, sometimes after two or tree weeks):

*org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxx.host.secureserver.net', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_342'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 105.0.5195.125, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 105.0.5195.52 (412c95e51883..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.MSRzur}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46595}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 7c1194aaa8290c084d2b8534655de1e2
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor85.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)*